# How to translate "drama actum est"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I want to translate the phrase *drama ingens in hac familia actum est* from Latin to English.
I know what the phrase means, but I struggle to find an idiomatic translation in English.

Is it just "a great drama has been acted in this family"?
The word I am unsure about is "act".
Should it rather be "enact", "act out", or something else, or would it be better to say "there was a great drama in this family"?

This phrase is a simplified version of something that will appear in a certain Latin performance, and it needs to be "subtitled" for the benefit of an international audience with a limited command of Latin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking Latin *drama* as English [*a drama, play*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DD%3Aentry+group%3D51%3Aentry%3Ddrama):

- *A great drama has been performed by this family*

  - This indicates that a particular family put on a performance of a play.  I.e., *The Collins family performed* The Sound of Music *for us, and it was great!*
- *A great drama has been acted out in this family*

  - This indicates that the events of the family's life unintentionally produced a dramatic story.  I.e., *It's terrible to say, but I love keeping an eye on the Collins family—their lives lately have been so interesting, and I can't wait to see how things turn out!*
  - *Performed* in place of *acted out* would result in a similar meaning, but to me would imply more intentionality.

In English *drama* can also refer more colloquially to *dramatic*:

- *There was a lot of drama in this family*

  - Many dramatic things happened within this family – usually referring to the interpersonal relationships within it.  I.e., *Now that Tina is back from school, there is a lot more drama with her sisters as they fight over who sleeps where, who gets the bathroom first, and who has the cutest boyfriend*.

Finally, here are a few notes on the options you suggested:

- *A great drama has been acted in this family*

  - This is not idiomatic.  "Acted" here needs to be "performed" or "acted out"
- *There was a great drama in this family*

  - This isn't idiomatic, except perhaps in the sense that the family was or will be responsible for the production of a great drama at some point in their lives.  Similar in sense to *Tina has a great song in her; she just needs to sit down and write it*.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go with "A great drama has been acted out in this family". The phrase refers to a single series of dramatic events, not an overall dramatic nature of the family.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest: "A great drama has been played out in this family".